# Drupal 7, JQuery и flexslider

Tags: jquery, drupal, slider

Главная проблема - не работает flexslider - поставил JQuery update, как советуют, но это не помогает.

в дебаге пишет:

> $(...).flexslider is not a function

заглянул в код странички :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
```

м.б. мешается лишний JQuery? 
если да - как исключить лишний?

UPD

полный код ошибки

> flexslider.load.js?ota23n:42 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is
>   not a function
>       at HTMLDivElement. (flexslider.load.js?ota23n:42)
>       at Function.each (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:4)
>       at $.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:4)
>       at $.fn.init.$.fn.once (jquery.once.js?v=1.2:55)
>       at _flexslider_init (flexslider.load.js?ota23n:35)
>       at Object.attach (flexslider.load.js?ota23n:25)
>       at Object. (drupal.js?ota23n:76)
>       at Function.each (jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2:4)
>       at Object.Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?ota23n:74)
>       at HTMLDocument. (drupal.js?ota23n:504)

Comment: похоже дело не в повторяющихся ссылках JQ

Comment: А где используется flexslider - в вашем js-файле?

Comment: @Byulent flexslider пробовал создавать и view и блоки - ни разу не получилось добиться необходимого результата

Comment: я про то, где находится сама функция `flexslider()`

Comment: @Byulent использую модули в друпале, об их внутренностях не имею представления. как это можно посмотреть?